# Is the runtime of df.groupby().transform() linear in the number of groups in the groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, entropy

**BACKGROUND**

I am calculating racial segregation statistics between and within firms using the [Theil Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil_index). The data structure is a multi-indexed pandas dataframe. The calculation involves a lot of `df.groupby()['foo'].transform()`, where the transformation is the `entropy` function from `scipy.stats`. I have to calculate entropy on smaller and smaller groups within this structure, which means calling `entropy` more and more times on the `groupby` objects. I get the impression that this is O(n), but I wonder whether there is an optimization that I am missing.

**EXAMPLE**

The key part of this dataframe comprises five variables: `county`, `firm`, `race`, `occ`, and `size`. The units of observation are counts: each row tells you the SIZE of the workforce of a given RACE in a given OCCupation in a FIRM in a specific COUNTY. Hence the multiindex:

`df = df.set_index(['county', 'firm', 'occ', 'race']).sort_index()`

The Theil Index is the size-weighted sum of sub-units' entropy deviations from the unit's entropy. To calculate segregation between counties, for example, you can do this:

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
from numpy import where


# Helper to calculate the actual components of the Theil statistic
define Hcmp(w_j, w, e_j, e):
    return where(e == 0, 0, (w_j / w) * ((e - e_j) / e))


df['size_county'] = df.groupby(['county', 'race'])['size'].transform('sum')
df['size_total'] = df['size'].sum()

# Create a dataframe with observations aggregated over county/race tuples
counties = df.groupby(['county', 'race'])[['size_county', 'size_total']].first()
counties['entropy_county'] = counties.groupby('county')['size_county'].transform(entropy, base=4) # <--
# The base for entropy is 4 because there are four recorded racial categories.
# Assume that counties['entropy_total'] has already been calculated.
counties['seg_cmpnt'] = Hcmp(counties['size_county'], counties['size_total'],
                             counties['entropy_county'], counties['entropy_total'])
county_segregation = counties['seg_cmpnt'].sum()
```

Focus on this line:

`counties['entropy_county'] = counties.groupby('county')['size_county'].transform(entropy, base=4)`

The starting dataframe has 3,130,416 rows. When grouped by county, though, the resulting groupby object has just 2,267 groups. This runs quickly enough. When I calculate segregation within counties and between firms, the corresponding line is this:

`firms['entropy_firm'] = firms.groupby('firm')['size_firm'].transform(entropy, base=4)`

Here, the groupby object has 86,956 groups (the count of firms in the data). This takes about 40 times as long as the prior, which looks suspiciously like O(n). And when I try to calculate segregation within firms, between occupations...

```
# Grouping by firm and occupation because occupations are not nested within firms
occs['entropy_occ'] = occs.groupby(['firm', 'occ'])['size_occ'].transform(entropy, base=4)
```

...There are 782,604 groups. Eagle-eyed viewers will notice that this is exactly 1/4th the size of the raw dataset, because I have one observation for each firm/race/occupation tuple, and four racial categories. It is also nine times the number of groups in the by-firm groupby object, because the data break employment out into nine occupational categories.

This calculation takes about nine times as long: four or five minutes. When the underlying research project involves 40-50 years of data, this part of the process can take three or four hours.

**THE PROBLEM, RESTATED**

I think the issue is that, even though `scipy.stats.entropy()` is being applied in a smart, vectorized way, the necessity of calculating it over a very large number of small groups--and thus calling it many, many times--is swamping the performance benefits of vectorized calculations.

I *could* pre-calculate the necessary logarithms that entropy requires, for example with `numpy.log()`. If I did that, though, I'd still have to group the data to first get each firm/occupation/race's share within the firm/occupation. I would also lose any advantage of readable code that looks similar at different levels of analysis.

Thus my question, stated as clearly as I can: is there a more computationally efficient way to call something like this entropy function, when calculating it over a very large number of relatively small groups in a large dataset?

Comment: Without having access to your data, it sounds a lot like the inefficiency is in the lack of parallelization, not execution.  It is entirely possible that the best way to speed this up is to simply use some platform which allows a large number of parallel computations.  In databricks for example you can use `applyInPandas()` to map your groupby df to a cluster of n workers, where n can be as large as you want to pay for.  I'd happily test this theory for you if the data was public.  https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/pandas-function-apis.html

Comment: Thank you for this, Chris. I agree that parallelization feels like the way to go. Alas, the data are confidential government stuff, which limits my ability to share them or leverage remote computes.